# Getting the rect/height of the text inside a static control

Tags: winapi

Is there a way to achieve something similar to SysLink's [`LM_GETIDEALHEIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for static controls, i.e. getting the size (or at least the height) of the actual text?

I have a multilingual program, and I want to position the controls accordingly, otherwise there's blank space left for some of the languages, which is not great.

Comment: [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx) "computes the width and height of the specified string of text." Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @trojansdestroy I'm aware of that function, but that's a major PITA using it. I think I prefer using SysLink without actually using links. Any drawback to this approach?

Comment: @trojansdestroy actually, I remember now why I rejected it - it doesn't support multiline texts.

Comment: What about [GetTextMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144941%28VS.85%29.aspx)? Sends metrics to a [TEXTMETRIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has a promising-looking `tmHeight`.

Comment: Still no go for multiline text - I can't specify the width.

Comment: [DrawTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499%28VS.85%29.aspx), then use the difference between `top` and `bottom` of the output RECT (`lprc`)?

Comment: `DrawTextEx` with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag.

Comment: Yes, `DrawTextEx` does the job, thanks @trojansdestroy and @JonathanPotter. I also had to do `SelectObject` with the control's font (perhaps obvious for you). You can create an answer so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DrawTextEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag (thanks to Jonathan Potter for that addition). Then find the difference between `top` and `bottom` of the output RECT object.